# How to use firebase cloud messaging over web

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am new on firebase and want to show notification over browser through firebase cloud messaging but problem is that i am confuse where to write this code ::

```
POST /fcm/send HTTP/1.1
Host: fcm.googleapis.com
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: key=YOUR_SERVER_KEY

{
  "notification": {
    "title": "New chat message!",
    "body": "There is a new message in FriendlyChat",
    "icon": "/images/profile_placeholder.png",
    "click_action": "http://localhost:5000"
  },
  "to":"YOUR_DEVICE_TOKEN"
}
```

please tell me in which file I'll have to write this code.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

That's a sample payload (see parameters [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref)). You generate a request from your own App Server or during development you could simply send downstream messages [using Postman](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45309674/fcm-with-postman-the-request-was-missing-an-authentication-key-fcm-token/45310143#45310143) or [cURL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44664911/firebase-cloud-messaging-send-click-action/44665817#44665817).

There's also the option of using [Firebase Notifications Console](https://firebase.corp.google.com/project/_/notification).